# Cannot build AuthView.swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, mobile

Disclaimer: I am doing this on Codecademy, so some of the code will reference it.

I cannot build AuthView.swift. I wrote the code but don't know how to remedy it. XCode says there is no error, but the footer is apparently the problem. Here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AuthView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = AuthViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        if viewModel.isAuthenticated {
            MainTabView()
        } else {
            NavigationView {
                SignInForm(viewModel: viewModel.makeSignInViewModel()) {
                    NavigationLink("Create Account", destination: CreateAccountForm(viewModel: viewModel.makeCreateAccountViewModel()))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private extension AuthView {
    struct SignInForm<Footer: View>: View {
        @StateObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel.SignInViewModel
        @ViewBuilder let footer: () -> Footer
        
        var body: some View {
            Form {
                TextField("Email", text: $viewModel.email)
                    .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                    .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                SecureField("Password", text: $viewModel.password)
                    .textContentType(.password)
            } footer: {
                Button("Sign In", action: viewModel.submit)
                    .buttonStyle(.primary)
                footer()
                    .padding()
            }
            .alert("Cannot Sign In", error: $viewModel.error)
            .disabled(viewModel.isWorking)
            .onSubmit(viewModel.submit)
        }
    }
}

private extension AuthView {
    struct CreateAccountForm: View {
        @StateObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel.CreateAccountViewModel
//        @ViewBuilder let footer: () -> Footer
        
        @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
        
        var body: some View {
            Form {
                TextField("Name", text: $viewModel.name)
                    .textContentType(.name)
                    .textInputAutocapitalization(.words)
                TextField("Email", text: $viewModel.email)
                    .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                    .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                SecureField("Password", text: $viewModel.password)
                    .textContentType(.newPassword)
            } footer: {
                Button("Create Account", action: viewModel.submit)
                    .buttonStyle(.primary)
                Button("Sign In", action: dismiss.callAsFunction)
                    .padding()
            }
            .alert("Cannot Create Account", error: $viewModel.error)
            .disabled(viewModel.isWorking)
            .onSubmit(viewModel.submit)
        }
    }
}

private extension AuthView {
    struct Form<Fields: View, Footer: View>: View {
        @ViewBuilder let fields: () -> Fields
        @ViewBuilder let footer: () -> Footer
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Socialcademy")
                    .font(.title.bold())
                fields()
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.secondary.opacity(0.15))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                footer()
            }
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct AuthView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AuthView()
    }
}
```

[Here is the error thrown by XCode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmSdE.png)

It gives the error: `extra trailing closure passed in call`

Comment: Share `AuthViewModel`.

Comment: I could run your code without any errors. Share specifically reproducible code.